# Help regarding distribution of error

Tags: distributions, t-distribution, residuals

I performed an OLS regression in R, and plotted the histograms of the residuals. I also plotted the theoretical Gaussian distribution with the same mean and standard deviation. I am attaching the plot. I cannot guess the distribution of the errors.

Should I model the error generating process? Or should I remove the outliers? 
[image: residualhistogram]

Comment: Answers to this questions are context-specific, so you need to add context!